# Кому продать душу чтобы помогли разместить картинку в футер?

Tags: html, css

Допустим у меня есть картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что и как мне нужно сделать чтобы оно занимало весь футер на любых разрешениях?

Comment: [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: `width: 100%`(Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width )

Comment: Лучше курсы по вёрстке купить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать два пути решения:

Картинка будет заполняться пропорционально контейнеру в данном случае футер

1. background-size: cover либо можно

2.`img {width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;   }`